# Multiple panels open and close at one click - Ant Design Collapse

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

So I have this `Custom Collapse` and everytime I toggle **1 panel**, all **4 of them open at the same time**.
Here's how I change the state between `parent component` and `child component`:

```js
//Parent Component

const [show, setShow] = useState(false)
const handleShow = (idx) => {
    setFollowed(prev => !prev)
  }
<AntCollapse isFollowed={followed[1]} show={show} keys="1" setShow={setShow} header="Follow XXX on Telegram">
     //some code
     <Row type='flex' align='middle' justify='center'>
         <Button onClick={() => {handleFollow(1); handleShow(); }} style={buttonStyle2} disabled={clicked}>Continue</Button> 
         <Button type='text' style={{color:'#EB7B59', border:'#f7f7f7', background:'#f7f7f7',height: "2em", fontSize:'16px', margin:'10px 0 0 10px'}}>Cancel</Button>
     </Row>
</AntCollapse>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------

//Child Component

const [key, setKey] = useState([props.keys]);
const handlePanelClose = () => props.setShow(prev => !prev);
<StyledCollapse accordian activeKey={props.show ? key : []} onChange={combineFunc}> 
      <AntCollapse.Panel
        {...props}
        header={props.header}
        showArrow={false}
        bordered={false}
        key={props.keys}
        extra={
            //some code
        }
      >
      {props.children}
      </AntCollapse.Panel>
</StyledCollapse>
```

How do I set the state for each panels individually?

Answer (score 0):

`setShow` is the only flag you are holding in order to decide whether or not to collapse a panel.

If you have multiple panels and you want each panel to have individual control, you should hold an object of flags `{ panel1 : true, panel2: false ...}` or list of flags `[true, false, true ..]` depending on your implementation.

You can render these panels within a loop for example, in such way that each one has a unique identifier that each child will receive from the parent component.

That way,  when you call `handleShow` from the child component - you could call it with an idendifier `handleShow(key)` and the parent component would know which one of the panels to collapse.

Parent -

```
const [show, setShow] = useState({})
const handleShow = (panelId) => {
    setShowArray({...show, panelId: !show[panelId})
  }
```

Comment: So I have added object of flags in my parent components which is `{1: false, 2: false ...}` then I passed the `show[1]` (take first panel as an example) to the custom collapse. Why is the panel not expanded even if the `props.show` is set to true and also the `key` array is not empty. Here's the link to my latest code: [here](https://pastebin.com/mB4fBSG2)

Comment: Maybe add your code to some kind of online editor where I could run the code. Anyways, this function has 2 issues - 

``` const handleShowPanel = (id) => { const val = !props.show props.setShow({[id] : val}) } ```

props.show is an Object - so the assignment of val= !props.show will always be false (sinse props.show exists it always returns true)
So you should get you value from !props.show[id]
In addition, when setting the new show object you would want to maintain the previous state and update a specific one, so use the spread operator - 
props.setShow({...props.show, id : val})